# Trying to show popup on pageshow, but it auto closes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I have a jQuery mobile page with a popup that needs to be shown on page load.
For some reason the popup shows and closes straightaway.
I'm using chrome on desktop. Tested on chrome on android, shows the same thing.
This is a test page which shows the same problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head> 
       <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("pageshow",function(){
                $("#testpopup").popup("open",{history:false});
            });
        </script>
   </head>
<body>

<div class="page01" data-role="page">
    <div id="page-content" data-role="content" data-theme="f">
        adasdf
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" data-history="false" data-dismissible="false" id="testpopup" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="content">
            ASDFASDFASDF
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You havent wrapped your script in jquery's `document.ready()` so I imagine it's firing before the dom has finished loading

Comment: @Dale `.ready` shouldn't be used in JQM.

Comment: @Omar thanks for the info, it's not a library I use often so I'll remember that if I ever do!

Comment: @Omar I tried to use setTimeout, works in desktop chrome but popup doesn't appear at all on android.

Comment: Increase delay 50-100ms should be fine. Another note, `pageshow` is deprecated in 1.4, use `pagecontainershow`.

Comment: I have timeout on 100ms and it's not working on my hp slate

Comment: @user1094553 have you tested on another device/platform?